Proof $| \psi |^2$ is probability density
Let's assume
$$\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3} | \psi |^2 d^3r=1$$
For some $t=t_0$. Then we want to calculate:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3} | \psi |^2 d^3r=\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{\partial | \psi |^2}{\partial t} d^3r=\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{i\hbar}{2m}\vec{\nabla}\cdot(\psi^*\vec{\nabla}\psi - \psi \vec{\nabla}\psi^*) d^3r:=-\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3}\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{j} d^3r=-\iint_{S_\infty}\vec{j}\cdot d\vec{s} $$
Now the argument is that $\vec{j}$ goes to zero as the bounds grow to infinity so the whole integral is zero. However when i read that argument I can't help but think about the Gauss law where we have an electric field which also goes to zero at infinity but:
$$\iint_{S_\infty}\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{s}=\frac{Q}{\varepsilon _0}$$
Can you prove more rigorously that the upper integral is zero? How do you prove $|\vec{j}|$ drops off faster than $\frac{1}{r^2}$?

You have to assume $|\psi|^2$ falls off quickly enough for the normalization integral to converge in the first place, then intuitively any derivative of $|\psi|^2$ should fall off at least as quickly if not more quickly. Maybe someone can give a more rigorous answer.

Also one of the issues here is that you introduce t as a differentiation variable so the equation is transformed into a PDE.

To make my comment into more of an answer, note that for the wavefunction to be normalizable,
$$
\int d^3 x |\psi|^2 = 1
$$
we need to assume that $|\psi|^2 \sim O(r^{-2})$, or in other words that $|\psi|^2$ falls off at least as quickly as $1/r^2$.
Then,
$$
j \sim \psi \nabla \psi^\star \sim \frac{\partial}{\partial r}(|\psi|^2) \sim O(r^{-3})
$$
where $\sim$ means "asymptotically equivalent". As some typical examples describing wavefunctions, if $|\psi^2| \sim r^{-n}$ (power law fall off), then $j \sim \psi \nabla \psi^\star \sim r^{-n-1}$, which is $O(r^{-3})$ for $n+1 \geq 3$, or in other words $n\geq 2$, which is what we needed to assume for $|\psi|^2$ to be normalizable. If $|\psi|^2 \sim e^{-r}$ (exponential fall off), then $j \sim \psi \nabla \psi^\star \sim e^{-r} \sim O(r^{-3})$ (ie, an exponential falls off much more quickly than $r^{-3}$.
Since we only need the current to fall off as fast as $r^{-2}$ for the boundary term to vanish, this guarantees the boundary term is zero. Intuitively, "probability can't flow outside of an infinite box."
Things get a little tricky for plane wave solutions, which are only delta function normalizable, and not really normalizable. There are various tricks to handle that case, (and a long story about "rigged Hilbert spaces" if you want to be mathematically rigorous), but in terms of current it still ends up being ok, intuitively since a plane wave represents a state of definite momentum, and any momentum that the plane wave brings into a sphere of radius $R$, it will also carry away.

There are wave functions not going to zero at infinity. However, in 1D, if you consider wave functions in the domain of the momentum operator, then indeed these vanish at infinity.

While this argument is probably right for physically realizable wavefunctions, I think you might have to be a little careful to be completely general, as demonstrated by a function like $\sin^2(k^2r^2)/r^2$

Here's a different approach; expand $\psi(r,t)$ in terms of the eigenstates $\phi_i$ of the Hamiltonian,
$$
 \psi(r, t) = \sum_i c_i \phi_i(r, t),$$
which is always possible because the eigenstates of $H$ form a complete set.
The eigenstates $\phi_i$ obey the time-independent Schrödinger equation $H \phi_i = E_i \phi_i$, and evolve in time as
$$\tag 1
\phi_i(r, t) = \phi_i(r, 0) e^{-i\frac{E_i}{\hbar}t}.$$
Now, in this basis, we have
$$\int |\psi(r,t)|^2 d r = \int \left|\sum_i c_i \phi_i(r,t)\right|^2 d r
= \sum_i |c_i|^2 \int   \left|\phi_i(r,t)\right|^2 d r = \sum_i |c_i|^2,$$
where the second-to-last equality holds due to the orthonomality of the eigenstates $\phi_i$, i.e.
$$\int \phi^*_i(r) \phi_j(r) d r = \delta_{ij}.$$
Since the expansion coefficients $c_i$ are independent of time, it is clear that so is $\int |\psi(r,t)|^2 d r$. Therefore, if $\psi$ is correctly normalized at one point in time, it will remain properly normalized at any time $t$.

I like Jakob KS's answer. I think it is the theoretically cleanest route to the desired end result, but it does not help the question asker along their own path.
So what has been asked is to show that the volume integral of $| \psi(x,t) |^2$ is constant in time. What has been established so far is that there is a continuity equation
$$\partial_t \rho(x,t) = \nabla \cdot j(x,t), $$
where the (probability) density is $\rho(x,t) = | \psi(x,t) |^2$ and the (probability) current is $j(x,t) = u(x,t) \rho(x,t) = \frac{i \hbar}{2 m } \nabla \cdot \nabla (\psi(x,t)^* \, \psi(x,t))$.
Your connection to Gauss's law is nice and it allows me to remind you that in that context the surface integral is non-zero if a "source" or "sink" of electric fields (i.e. charge +Q or -Q) is within your surface $S$. The same is true in the context of quantum mechanics. The probability flux into the surface $S$ (+ contribution) will cancel with the probability flux out of the surface $S$ (- contribution)... UNLESS you have some probability source or sink (e.g. radioactive decay) inside the surface $S$.

For OP, in the electrostatic case, consider what is $\iint_{S_\infty}\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{s}$ when the source is a dipole rather than a single (unbalanced) charge. You are still working with the same electrostatic Gauss's Law, but now you have got 0 on the r.h.s. The difference is the nature of the source, not Gauss's Law itself.

When you assume that $$\int_\mathbb{R^3} |\psi|^2 d^3 r = 1$$
you are implicitly assuming that $\psi$ represents a bound state of a finite system. This is because scattering states (like a free particle with momentum $k$, where $\psi \propto e^{i k.r}$) cannot be normalized!
If $\psi$ is a bound state of a finite system then it will decay to zero exponentially in regions far away from the system, and therefore you can be sure that the boundary term in the integral will vanish!
If you work in solid state physics, you might instead use Born von karman boundary conditions. Then you take the system to reside in a big box of side length $L$, impose periodic boundary conditions, and let $L$ go to infinity. That can be used to model extended systems. In this case, the boundary term will vanish again! not because the wave function vanishes, but because of the periodic boundary condition.
